# OwnCloud enhance core features with App (eg. user registration)

Tags: owncloud

I started looking into OwnCloud app development to add some capabilities I would like to my server.  To me it seems like Apps can't modify anything like the Login page or User Management page.  Is this the case?

I want to build a user registration app and would love to integrate it into the user management page (if not and it has to exist as its own app page not a big deal).  The one big problem I see so far is not being able to add a "Register" link to the login page.  I could just go in and add it to the source manually, but I would like to keep the App self contained so others can use it too.

If this is not possible to do in an App I may just need to modify the core application and then see if they will accept my feature addition in a pull request.

Thanks to anyone who can shed some light on this for me.  I don't want to waste my time trying to figure out how to do it with an App on the platform if it wont be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging around I did figure out a way to do this.

In the App's app.php file, you can force a script to be loaded if the plugin is enabled:

```
$api->addScript('script_name'); // without .js
```

In that script jQuery can be used to add the elements to the page where you need them.

This was a good solution for me since I only needed to add a single button to the login page.  I can see this being a bad idea if you want to make vast modifications.  At that point you might as well just create a separate page that you have full control over.